# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished randomly occured in deployed instance after migrate from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration, amazon-rds

After upgrade from Rails `5.2` to `6.0`
I got this error randomly but not often when exploratory testing in a deployed instances in AWS.

When it happened it persisted for a while

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
No connection pool with 'primary' found.

But it **never found in local** with the same configure.
(Both connect to the same DB)

Any suggestion or solution would be helpful.
Thank you.

The **drastically dropped** connection count found when this error occurred

**Error and RDS connection count**

[image]

Log from server when error occured

```
2021-03-25 10:58:14 +0700 Using rack adapter
TRG Started 2021-03-25 10:58:19 +0700
2021-03-25 10:58:20 +0700 Thin web server (v1.8.0 codename Possessed Pickle)
2021-03-25 10:58:20 +0700 Maximum connections set to 1024
2021-03-25 10:58:20 +0700 Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, CTRL+C to stop
...

2021-03-25 11:13:36 +0700 Unexpected error while processing request: No connection pool with 'primary' found.
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1146:in `retrieve_connection'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:221:in `retrieve_connection'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:189:in `connection'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:193:in `block in pluck'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:839:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:193:in `pluck'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:52:in `all_versions'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1084:in `get_all_versions'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1091:in `current_version'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1191:in `current_version'
    /data/acm-trg/lib/rack/health_check.rb:35:in `rail_migration_version'
    /data/acm-trg/lib/rack/health_check.rb:15:in `call'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:74:in `block in call'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in `each'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in `call'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:50:in `block in process'
    /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1077:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
```

**Updated**

- Upgrade from aurora mysql 5.6 to 5.7 **do not fix** this issue

Comment: can you please add server logs

Comment: @SikandarTariq Sure
Updated to main post

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ArsalanAhmad 
I still try to fix it.
Did you got the same issue?

Comment: yes, I also have the same problem. I seem to have tried everything but nothing works so far. Let us know if you find a solution

Comment: I'm contacting the AWS support to verify this issue.
I suggest it caused from RDS behavior.
So I need more info for this investigation.

@ArsalanAhmad - Which DB engine your're using in RDS? I'm using Aurora MySQL
Which Rails and Ruby version dud you using?

Comment: Upgrade from aurora mysql 5.6 to 5.7 not fix this issue

Comment: Hey, we found the issue for our application and it was not related to Aurora database. One of the developer in our company was calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` in a health check route. It cancelled the previous connection pool and created new one. After removing that, we are not experiencing similar issue again.

Comment: @ArsalanAhmad

That's straight to the root point.
I'll need fix the health check to use another way.

Could you add your as the Answer?
So I can mark it as correct.
If no, I can summary the answer myself.
Just wanna give you a credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your application is not calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` manually for example, inside a health check route. Calling `establish_connection` is not required as ActiveRecord establishes its own connection automatically in Rails.

When you call this method yourself, it destroys the old database connection pool and recreates another one.

Comment: For anybody whi concern.
I follow this article for the implementation. It's work for Rail <=5.2
But failed on Rail 6.0 and over 

https://medium.com/@goncalvesjoao/how-to-have-a-working-health-endpoint-while-rails-is-500ring-509efc1da42c

Comment: Thanks, this definitely saved me a headache. It was the solution to the issue, happening intermittently on Rails 7.